# What kind of impact tests to large touch screen displays in crew capsules have to pass?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, safety, instrument, capsule, qualification-testing

Some of the glass layers in commercial large format displays are between 0.25 and 0.7 mm thick. (e.g. [1](https://www.corning.com/media/worldwide/cdt/documents/Lotus_NXT_Glass_PI%20-%20FINAL%20-Eng.pdf), [2](https://www.corning.com/cala/es/products/display-glass/products/eagle-xg-slim.html)) If something comes loose in a capsule during a high acceleration period (launch, reentry) and the capsule were tilted in a strange way (unlikely) "down" could be toward the touch screens.

While this is an unlikely scenario, I'm guessing there must be some impact testing standards that these big thin sheets of glass-containing mission-critical displays must pass.

**Question:** What kind of impact tests to large touch screen displays in crew capsules have to pass? There might be a difference between purely private endeavors and those in which NASA is involved, if so my primary interest is those associated with NASA.

---

Random ball drop test videos:

- AGC FlatGlass: [ball drop test](https://youtu.be/iqMmdHZkt5E)
- Gelivable Glass: [Drop ball test of 3.0mm AG glass](https://youtu.be/LtmRgbKLxqs)
- Scriptel Corporation: [Scriptel Signature Pad Glass Ball Drop Test - 60 Inches](https://youtu.be/TVpwdJfTY2M)